# Creating A Dynamic TableView with Custom Cells

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I'm looking to make a questionnaire app and trying to figure out the best way to implement this.

I'm familiar with TableViews and how to load content into them from an array but I'm having trouble figuring out a way to create a dynamic `TableView` that can expand or shrink depending on how many questions are asked per view.

My questions will be grouped so that each "page" will only display 1 group of question or questions at a time. This can vary from 1 question or more.

Every question will have 3 attributes of:

- `questionNumber`, `questionLabel`, and `questionType`.  These are all strings.

There are 7 question types which are:

- `yesNo`, `date`, `time`, `search`, `multipleSelection`, `textField` and `prompt`.

  Do I need to create custom cells for each and load them into the `TableView` or could I make separate Views that would then be loaded into a `TableView`?

I'm also going to use either a toolbar or a navbar to for the user to tap which would be next to go to the next group of questions or tap on previous which would get them back to the previous group of questions.

Any help to point me in the right direction would be appreciated.  As of right now I would need to make 15 different view controllers and looking to possibly reduce the amount by just creating a `TableView` that would expand and shrink with questions and `questionType`.  One page might only show a yes or no question while another page might have 2 or more questions each with a different `questionType` attached to them.

Comment: i believe it will be easier to have one view controller and 15 arrays with questions, just reload tableView with new questions when needed, make custom cells for that

Comment: Try collectionview instead of tabbleview